# Use google apps script to increment a column on Google Sheets by 1?

Tags: google-apps-script

Not sure how to go about incrementing the number values on my google spreadsheet by 1 with a button, the script I'm using only increments the first cell and copies that down. How can I make the script increment the whole column and it's individual cells by 1?

```
function increment(){
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C2:C86");
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();
  cell.setValue(cellValue + 1);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to add 1 to the cells of "C2:C86".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script:

```
function increment(){
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C2:C86");
  var cellValues = cell.getValues().map(function(row) {return [row[0] + 1]}); // Modified
  cell.setValues(cellValues); // Modified
}
```

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve the values from the cells of "C2:C86".
2. Add 1 for the value of each cell.
3. Put the values to the range of "C2:C86".

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.